# scanner/scanning: Duplicate?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do the tags [scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanner) and [scanning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanning) both exist? Are they exact duplicates? If not, the `scanning` tab could do with a tag wiki to resolve the ambiguity. (The `scanner` tag already has one.)

Comment: Interesting discussion here... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my mind, these are obviously exact duplicates. (Unless I am missing something.)

Comment: And yet both tags still exist. Is there anything we can do about that?