# Tag Synonym Request: [scanning] -> [scanner]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Since,

- [I would argue that these tags have no difference in meaning](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2745) (this thread has a +9/-1 score),
- [scanning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanning) has no wiki, while [scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanner) does,
- the tag synonym suggestion mechanism is fundamentally broken on smaller sites

Could a mod make [scanning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanning) a synonym of [scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scanner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we waited long enough. Synonym proposal sat at 2 votes for over a month.

I've approved it now.

Answer (score -2):

[I have created a *suggested* synonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/scanner/synonyms). Anybody* who agrees with the suggestion can vote for it, anybody who doesn't can vote against it.

This may seem long-winded (especially with consensus a few years ago) but this is the way synonyms are supposed to be made these days, not moderators pushing everything through on very light opinion.

* This isn't open to everybody, there are rules:

> Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: Problems, is /tags/synonyms has barely any publicity. There's little indication about it in the general UI (compare close votes or edit review queues). And often, barely enough active *and* eligible users for voting.

Comment: I agree with @muru. The tag synonym suggestion mechanism is not fit for purpose on any sites other than SO.

Comment: I'd like to agree with Oli, but of the users with the required score only 4 (!!) are active (including both myself and Oli). Now add the low visibility of the synonym page and the confusing way it works there's pretty much 0 chance this could happen "organically". Besides, if enough users agree to it but don't happen to have the score in the tag how else is it supposed to get done?