# Merge the tags "schedule" and "scheduled"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Both the tags [schedule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/schedule) and [scheduled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scheduled) exist, but usage is fully identical. It seems inefficient, could they be merged into [schedule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/schedule) (which is used slightly more often)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the list of top users for [schedule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/schedule), you are capable of suggesting a synonym for it, and there are more than five other users with a score of 5. The top user is [Mitch♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch), and I guess his vote as a mod would be binding. So, perhaps you should suggest [scheduled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scheduled) as [a snyonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/schedule/synonyms), and pester Mitch to vote on it. Considering how long we have been waiting on [Tag Synonym Request: [scanning] -> [scanner]](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14174/158442), that might be fastest way.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, done.

Comment: I've approved it.

Comment: @Seth Nooooooo! What happened to pestering Mitch? (Thanks! Could you also take care of that scanner tag?)

Comment: @muru Already done :)

Comment: @Seth Perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I would tend to agree. A brief look at the questions involved indicate that the existing [schedule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/schedule) tag could easily be used for the questions using the [scheduled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scheduled)  tag. I don't believe there is a downside to taking this action.

Comment: Obviously, I agree :)